# Side-effect free functions

Tags: javascript, eval

Creating online learning material for mathematics, I want to allow users of my website to define (mathematical) functions, which are, by definition, side-effect free. The easiest way to achieve this is by doing the following

```
// ... get string entered by user and store it in variable user_code
// now build function
var user_function = eval ("(function (x) { return (" + user_code + "); })");
```

If the users enters `x*x`, `user_function` will contain a function that calculates the square of its argument.

Now this opens my page to cross-site scripting and malicious code.

Is there any way to avoid this, apart from writing an expression parser myself? In other words, I want to allow execution of functions in a well-defined context, for example, without the function accessing global variables.

Comment: so only `x` should be able to be accessed in `user_code`?

Comment: yes, that's the idea -- only arguments explicitly passed to the function

Comment: If the user does define the functions only for himself, does not store them on the server for other users or get function contents by url parameters, there is no XSS attack.

Comment: So I can be sure that the user will, at worst, mess up the layout of the page he sees?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's not a risk as they could just enter the bad code in their console if they wanted. You just need to ensure that nobody else can inject code into a user's page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are lots of good expression parsers that already exist for javascript, why re-invent the wheel?

I'm sure it'll be easier and safer to use something like [math.js](http://mathjs.org/) that has an expression parser built-in...